# Java configuration for int-jms:outbound-channel-adapter from spring integration

Tags: java, spring, jms, spring-integration

I am trying to convert a XML based configuration to JAVA based configuration. Can someone please let me know the java annotation based configuration for the following

```
<jms:outbound-channel-adapter channel="requestChannel"
                              connection-factory="testConnectionFactory"
                              destination-name="${jms.queueName}" 
                              message-converter="messageConverter"/>
```

I tried having a look at this [Reference doc](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/htmlsingle/#_configuring_with_java_configuration_3). But i am not able to understand how do I map the above xml to the annotation config.

Answer (score 1):

```
@ServiceActivator(inputChannel="requestChannel")
@Bean
public MessageHandler outbound(JmsTemplate jmsTemplate) {
    JmsSendingMessageHandler handler = new JmsSendingMessageHandler(jmsTemplate);
    handler.setDestinationName(...);
    ...
    return handler;
}

@Bean
public JmsTemplate jmsTemplate(ConnectionFactory jmsConnectionFactory) {
    ...
    template.setMessageConverter(converter());
    return template;
}
```

Then add the connection factory and converter beans.

**EDIT**

Also pay attention to [Spring Integration Java DSL](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-java-dsl) project, which provides the `org.springframework.integration.dsl.jms.Jms` Factory on the matter. You can find its usage in the `JmsTests`: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-java-dsl/blob/master/src/test/java/org/springframework/integration/dsl/test/jms/JmsTests.java